# array of typedef struct pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have following in my header file

```
typedef struct tree_node* TreeNode;

struct tree_node{

    int value;
    void *data;

    TreeNode parent;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

};
```

To create a treenode I am doing following

```
TreeNode createTreeNode(int value, void *data){

    TreeNode node;

    node = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode*));

    if(node == NULL){
        printf("TreeNode malloc failed!!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    node->data = data;
    node->value = value;
    node->parent = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->left = NULL;

    return node;

}
```

Now I want create array of TreeNodes...how would I do it?
I was thinking following

```
TreeNode *treeNodes;
treeNodes = malloc(26 * sizeof(TreeNode));
```

And then

```
treeNodes[a_number_between_0_to_25] = createTreeNode(intNodeValue, NULL);
```

Comment: Replace sizeof(TreeNode*) to sizeof(TreeNode) since size of a pointer is not the size of the struct itself

Comment: `typedef struct tree_node* TreeNode;` isn't good idea. It hides the fact that `TreeNode` is actually a pointer. Let `TreeNode` be an alias for `struct tree_node` and use `TreeNode*` instead.

Comment: Do you really want an array of TreeNodes (in other words, pointers) or an array of tree_node structs?

Comment: I totally agree with LihO, do yourself and everyone else a favour and use `typedef struct tree_node TreeNode; ... TreeNode *parent; ...`.

Comment: @Liho You are right I should change it typedef to struct than to struct pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode*));` will only allocate 4 bytes(or 8 depending on the size of a pointer). This is wrong. Use `sizeof(struct tree_node);` or you will end up with segmentation violation.

Other than that, your code looks ok. and yes, that is how you can create an array.

Look into VLAs as well(Variable Length Arrays)

Comment: @AmitPatil cool, I hope the solution I posted solves the problem?

Comment: Should I use typedef struct* or typedef struct?

Comment: @AmitPatil use `typedef struct tree_node TreeNode, *PTreeNode;` if you do not like to see `*` everywhere. This is how `Hungarian` notation works.

Comment: Is it true that "typedef struct tree_node TreeNode" exposes struct to outer world?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "exxposes to the outer world" @AmitPatil